# Не работает автодополнение PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Не могу разобраться с автокомплитом в PhpStorm.
В один прекрасный момент перестало работать автодополнение для JavaScript.
То есть я начинаю вводить команду alert,
появляется список возможных вариантов, но alert среди них нет.
То же при вводе например prompt.
Если ввести руками до конца и поставить скобки, то появляется подсказка какие аргументы должны быть.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

проблему решил.
в редакторе заходим
file / Invalidate Caches
локальная история при этом очищается
все заработало